# Replacing Range of lines in file PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, file, replace

I have been at this for a while and I have tried many different "replace between, needle / haystack" methods and functions, but in my text file, I wish to **just remove line 1 - 33**, retaining the rest of the file data.

I have tried working with this

```
function replace_all_text_between($str, $start, $end, $replacement) {

    $replacement = $start . $replacement . $end;

    $start = preg_quote($start, '/');
    $end = preg_quote($end, '/');
    $regex = "/({$start})(.*?)({$end})/";

    return preg_replace($regex,$replacement,$str);
}

$myfile = file_get_contents('/usr/local/www/site.com/serve/recentImage1.txt');

$string = '------WebKitFormBoundaryDy3HUVBjHmCBUyXm
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="id"

c31
------WebKitFormBoundaryDy3HUVBjHmCBUyXm
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="created"

2021-05-21T00:51:22.555Z
------WebKitFormBoundaryDy3HUVBjHmCBUyXm
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="modified"

2021-05-21T00:51:22.555Z
------WebKitFormBoundaryDy3HUVBjHmCBUyXm
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="pings"

[object Object]
------WebKitFormBoundaryDy3HUVBjHmCBUyXm
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fullname"

You
------WebKitFormBoundaryDy3HUVBjHmCBUyXm
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="profile_picture_url"

/images/avatars/8cc11eb4cb12c3d7e00abfba341c30b32ced49be_thumb.jpg
------WebKitFormBoundaryDy3HUVBjHmCBUyXm
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="created_by_current_user"

true
------WebKitFormBoundaryDy3HUVBjHmCBUyXm
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="attachments_to_be_created"; filename="dbresult 2.png"
Content-Type: image/png';

echo replace_all_text_between($string, '------WebKitFormBoundaryDy3HUVBjHmCBUyXm', 'Content-Type:', 'REMOVED'); // (hey) how it (hey) here{
```

This is what I have tried. The $string var contains the content that is streamed and put inside a PNG file with **file_put_contents()**.

How to simply remove this range of **lines 1 - line 33** saving the original file??

Any help greatly appreciated !

Comment: have you tried using [`file()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php)?

Comment: file() - Best way to force associative array on target file. In this case, it turned 90% of the data as a 1-key array, which doesn't apply here. Answer accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to remove some lines from a file or string. You don't need search and replace if you know the line numbers. Here is my solution for this,

```
function remove_lines($content, $from, $to){
    $array = explode("\n", $content);
    array_splice($array, $from - 1, $to - 1);
    return implode("\n", $array);
}

$content = file_get_contents('test.txt'); // or other methods to get the file content
$newContent = remove_lines($content, 1, 34);
```

Beware that in my method, `$from` is inclusive but `$to` is exclusive.

Comment: Thank you. This is what we were after :)